# Why does setting a key/value pair of list of dictionaries fill all dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

```py
test = [{}]*5 # Creates [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
print(test[1]) # outputs "{}"

test[1]['asdf'] = 5

print(test)
```

This gives `test` as `[{'asdf': 5}, {'asdf': 5}, {'asdf': 5}, {'asdf': 5}, {'asdf': 5}]`. Somehow, all the dictionaries in the list have been set to the same value

But this doesn't happen if we initialize the list a different way:

```py
test2 = [{} for i in range(5)] # Also [{}, {}, {}, {}, {}]
test2[1]['asdf'] = 1

print(test2)
```

`test2` now equals `[{}, {'asdf': 1}, {}, {}, {}]`, the expected result.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly

Comment: Because `[{}]*5` creates a list with five references to the same list*

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the two is that for `[{}]*5`, Python creates a 5 element list containing *the* dictionary given in the square brackets. Ie. it's 5 different *references* to the same dictionary.

While the other method creates a new dictionary for every element in the list.

More detailed explanation can be found in the [duplicate question link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/240205/7564988)